# Dimensionless non-relativistic energy of fast particles

Tags: dimensional-analysis, plasma-physics

In Plasma Astrophysics, Part 1, Equation (4.7)

the dimensionless non-relativistic energy of fast particles ($m$) in a plasma with electrons ($m_e$) and protons ($m_p$) is defined as,

$$
x = \frac{m v^2}{2 k_B T} \bigg( \frac{m_e}{m} \bigg)
$$

Why is it defined like this? This is just

$$
\frac{m_e v^2 / 2}{k_B T}
$$

which is the kinetic energy of electrons divided by the mean kinetic energy. The information about fast particle does not come anywhere.

Comment: Kinetic energy is direct information about how fast a particle is traveling though, but you need something to compare it to.

Comment: I'd need to see the calculation in context, but I suspect it's argued the mass ratio explains an energy transfer, so $mv^2/2$ is relevant at one stage but $m_ev^2/2$ at another.